# Why Scala doesn't have enum type and what are benefits of current design?

Tags: scala, language-design

What is the reason why they decided not to implement **enum** type in Scala ? What are benefits of current language design (defining object and extending **scala.Enumeration** instead of creating new **enum** type ) ?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Have you tried researching this yourself before posting?

Comment: Scala has case classes, which use a lingually different construct to create named elements. It matches java enum closely. Or one uses Enumeration.

Comment: @DanW It's not homework question. Yes, I did a little research and I haven't find answer to my question. They all present solutions, how-to's, but none of them mention or discuss why was it made that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see any reasonable benefits of Enumeration in it's current state and tend to think it is design flaw that scala community is [trying to overcome](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-internals/8RWkccSRBxQ/discussion). It is not easy, but I guess this is definitely will be done in next two major scala versions. In all scala code I've seen sealed object hierarchy was given a preference.

Comment: +1 for sealed `object` hierarchy. They work really well and give you everything that a java-like enum would.